# In what situations do throwing an object use less energy than carrying it?

Tags: classical-mechanics, biophysics

This relates to humans carrying or throwing rocks, so it relates both to mechanics and biophysics.

Let's say you stand at point A where there is a pile of rocks. You need to get the rocks to point B. You can choose between 1) carrying them or 2) throwing all of them as far as you can, and then walking to the new pile and repeat until they are at B. A and B can have an elevation difference.

There are a lot of factors in play here, but my intuition says that it will always be easier (less energy consumed) to throw the rocks than to carry them, no matter the elevation difference between A and B. Is that correct? Or are there cases when this is not true, and if so, where is the breaking point?

I assume that human throwing mechanics and carrying/walking mechanics are somewhat similar in energy efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: it depends on friction.

If we equate a human walking carrying rocks to rolling them along the ground, then you can imagine a scenario whereby rolling this on a a surface with incredibly high friction takes an immense effort, in which case throwing the rocks through (presumably) air would require less energy. I doubt this would ever be realised in reality, but you could calculate the frictional force required to necessitate more energy being put into rolling an object compared to throwing it through a vacuum, for example.

If we then consider picking up a rock and walking with it, you essentially have to do the same (save the energy required to pick up the rock) but calculate the energy loss required to overcome friction while walking.

Comment: High friction isn't too relevant for rolling as long as there is no slipping occurring. Perhaps you mean to say "sliding" rather than "rolling"?

Comment: I disagree, due to the energy "dumped" when the thrown rock hits the ground.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft "*If we equate a human walking carrying rocks to rolling them along the ground, then you can imagine a scenario whereby rolling this on a a surface with incredibly high friction takes an immense effort*" I was referencing this part of the post. I don't see anywhere in this post where friction during dumping is discussed, so I don't see how my comment could have been referring to that.

Comment: @BioPhysicist the way comments work is that they are directed to the person posting the question or the answer unless specifically addressed to another person.  I apologize for the confusion, as I was not responding to your comment.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Sorry, I got notified so I thought it was towards me :). I should have seen I was not tagged.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of question I would assign to a class more to see **how** they answer rather than to claim there is only one correct answer.

For one example: suppose you pick the rock up just a cm or so to clear the ground, carry it over, and gently deposit it. You could calculate the net Work done to lift, accelerate to a constant horizontal speed, stop & then drop.  Or you could calculate the energy your body burned to offset the force of gravity and maintain altitude.

Then calculate the energy you imparted to throw a rock, using the usual parabolic arc rule where a 45-degree launch angle is optimal, and observe that energy dissipated as heat and probably smashing stuff apart when the rock lands.   See if you've accounted for all energy expended and find out whether the Work  ( = integral of Force over the path ) comes out the same.